# C# . Explanation about the code converted from VB

Tags: c#

I am using a converter that converted the following VB code

```
Public Event Progress(ByVal Percent As Integer)
```

to C#

```
public delegate void ProgressEventHandler(int Percent);
private ProgressEventHandler ProgressEvent;

public event ProgressEventHandler Progress
{
    add
    {
        ProgressEvent = (ProgressEventHandler) System.Delegate.Combine(ProgressEvent, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        ProgressEvent = (ProgressEventHandler) System.Delegate.Remove(ProgressEvent, value);
    }
}
```

That seems quite a lot of code. I was expecting just these 3 lines.

```
public delegate void ProgressEventHandler(int Percent);
private ProgressEventHandler ProgressEvent;
public event ProgressEventHandler Progress;
```

and then later I invoke the event in this way

```
void OnProgress(int p) {
    ProgressEvent?.Invoke (p);
}
```

So what exactly I need to know is what is the advantage of the Progress body (with add and remove). Should I stick to my own code or use the code by the converter? Which one is better?

Comment: i guess you're actually decompiling?

Comment: @LeiYang... Just because you "guess" that I am decompiling doesn't mean that you are right. It is just about the knowledge and understanding the code. And I think we are here to increase the knowledge about what we don't already know, or we need help understanding it.

Comment: i said that because i did not see any relationship between your code and vb.

Comment: @LeiYang That is very surprising if you can not see any relationship. And if you are the down-voter then you should better improve your own knowledge before down voting.

Comment: i did not downvote... if you do not believe then i can show you my devote

Comment: The down-voter should at least provide the reason. My question is well written and closely ended, and clear. I can't understand why it is down voted.

Comment: Maybe you should mention what converter you are using. “A converter” could be anything, and I have to agree with Lei Yang, that this looks more like a conversion based on decompiled IL (as mentioned in my answer). [Telerik’s converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) for example correctly converts this to an automatically implemented event.

Comment: I am using tool form www.vbconversions.com.

Comment: I am not decompiling, but if I were doing it, does it make any point I can not improve my knowledge by asking question about part of code I am unable to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `System.Delegate.Combine` and `System.Delegate.Remove` calls are just verbose ways of doing the following:

```
// combine
ProgressEvent += value;

// remove
ProgressEvent -= value;
```

Which turns the event member into the following:

```
private ProgressEventHandler ProgressEvent;
public event ProgressEventHandler Progress
{
    add
    {
        ProgressEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        ProgressEvent -= value;
    }
}
```

And at that time, it’s equivalent to the auto-implemented event member:

```
public event ProgressEventHandler Progress;
```

So, this is essentially just a verbose way of defining the event and event handler, but which really means just the same. I assume that the converter that you were using just uses the verbose way to be able to handle non-standard solutions easier. And maybe it is generating this from the compiled IL, at which point this all looks more or less the same.

Btw. your expected code won’t work since the `Progress` event and the handler `ProgressEvent` are not linked (so if you want to split those members, you *need* to implement the event explicitly).

Comment: This code is part of a class, and when I create object of that class, I add this line .. obj.Progress += new ProgressEventHandler (myhandler); So isn't it linked there? (BTW thanks for explanation)

Comment: @Khan `Progress` and `ProgressEvent` are only linked if `Progress` (the event member) was not automatically implemented and explicitly added the handlers to the `ProgressEvent` member. Otherwise they are not linked, no. An automatically implemented `Progress` event member will get its own private backing field when you compile.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.